# Is there an alternative way to switch between chrome windows?

Tags: google-chrome, mac

I'm using `` Cmd-` `` to cycle through chrome windows.

I have currently 6 chrome windows, and it's hard to navigate between them.
(Each window has handful of tabs open)

Is there an better altenative?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer

You can setup a shortcut for viewing `all windows for currently active application`
I think default key binding is `ctrl-arrow_down`

https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-see-all-open-windows-on-mac-at-once-3663530/